# Asking recruiter about job after offer is made?

Tags: interviewing, professionalism, job-search

I applied for a position at CompanyX and received an offer, which I’m still evaluating.

While searching, I found about other jobs at CompanyX, which seem very interesting.

Is it wrong to ask the recruiter about these other vacancies even though I received an offer from them?

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: It's too simple and undeveloped. Why are you hesitant? It seems obvious to just have a conversation about it with your recruiter, so perhaps you know more about this but haven't bothered elaborating. We don't have much context. I tried my best.

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to ask. The recruiter will have a good understanding of that role, your fit, and how bureaucratically easy it would be to slide into that process. So will the hiring manager, but he or she might not be keen to hold your offer after all the hard the team put in on your behalf. It could go your way, but if the answer is "no", accept it without push back unless you've decided your current offer is expendable.